# Cognos - Crosstab report broken out by DateRange (week starting on Sunday)

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I've been working on this a while and I haven't found too much on the web to help so hopefully someone can assist.

I'm using Cognos 8.4.1 with SQL Server as a data source. I have a date field that holds date and time.

Our client would like to see the report broken out by week for the entire year, but with the week starting on Sunday, not Monday. To add to the complexity, I need to display the date range as the data label.

so for example the header of the cross tab would look like the below breakout, the totals in each column.

Week 1/5-1/11 | 1/12-1/18 | 1/19-1/25 | 1/25-2/1 |

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your data source a data warehouse or an operational system? If its a data warehouse you should build a calendar table to satisfy this (and many other) date based business rules. If it's directly from an operational system, then please post the query you are currently using.

Comment: Agree with ElecticLlama. Use Cognos purely to pull the modeled data. Creating a date dimension table or one-off reporting table to satisfy this requirement is a far better an easier solution.

Comment: We have a data warehouse. So should the table consist of two fields, week start and week end?

Answer (score 1):

So the ideal way is to in fact have a table with the calendar data in order to do this properly. This isn't something I can add to our Cognos environment overnight, so in interim I've come up with a temporary solution. Instead of displaying the week range, I'm displaying the start of each week (Sunday).

I created a new data element calling it [DayOfWeek]:

```
_day_of_week([mydatefield], 7)
```

Then I created another data element calling it [StartOfWeek]:

```
cast(CASE [DayofWeek] 
WHEN 1 THEN [mydatefield] 
ELSE _add_days([mydatefield], -1 * ([DayofWeek] - 1)) 
END,date)
```

My biggest challenge was using the add days function because I started with DATEADD, the native function of SQL and it wasn't working.

Thanks everyone for your input!

Comment: Don't forget about putting the calendar table 'on the table' A data warehouse without a calendar table isn't really a datawarehouse.